# REST API insert is not working using node-oracledb

Tags: oracle, express, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I try to make RESTFUL API with node js and oracle database for my first time

I make a table in the database named "EMPLOYEES" and I add some data there

I make my backend file and I try to get the information in the database and it's worked successfuly

but when I try to make  POST to add a new employee I don't get an error and the employee is not added to the database

when I try to test it with POSTMAN I got this result a null object like this  `{}`

I know that I'm missing something

```js
const express = require('express')
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const bodyPerser=require("body-parser")
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var password = 'mypassword';
app.use(bodyPerser.json());

async function selectAllEmployees(req, res) {
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: "system",
      password: password,
      connectString: "localhost:1521/XE"
    });

    console.log('connected to database');
    // run query to get all employees
    result = await connection.execute(`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES`);

  } catch (err) {
    //send error message
    return res.send(err.message);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        // Always close connections
        await connection.close();
        console.log('close connection success');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    }
    if (result.rows.length == 0) {
      //query return zero employees
      return res.send('query send no rows');
    } else {
      //send all employees
      //return res.send(result.rows);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
      console.log(result.metaData[0].name);
      let list=[]
      result.rows.forEach(element => {
        let agent = {
          "ID": element[0],
          "EMPNAME": element[1],
          "EMPLASTNAME": element[2],
          "AGE":element[3]
        }
        list.push(agent)
      });
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
      
    }

  }
}

//get /employess
app.get('/employees', function (req, res) {
  selectAllEmployees(req, res);
})

//////////////////post//////////////////////


app.post("/addNewEmployee", async (req, res) => {
   try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: "system",
      password: password,
      connectString: "localhost:1521/XE"
    });
    console.log('connected to database');
    // I don't know what i'm missing here 
    result=connection.execute(`INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES  VALUES ('${req.body.ID}','${req.body.EMPNAME}','${req.body.EMPLASTNAME}','${req.body.AGE}')`);
    
res.send(result)
  } catch (err) {
    //send error message
    return res.send(err.message);
  } 
  
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("nodeOracleRestApi app listening on port %s!", port))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) and make sure you have basic techniques covered e.g. using bind variables. (The way you build your INSERT is open to SQL injection security attacks).  Look at how `webapp.js` uses a connection pool - which you'll need if you have more than one person accessing your service.

Make sure you commit the data after inserting.

Add an 'await' before your `connection.execute()` for INSERT, something like:

```
result = await connection.execute(`INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (:id, :empname, :emplastname, :age)`,
    [req.body.ID, req.body.EMPNAME, req.body.EMPLASTNAME, req.body.AGE],
    {autoCommit: true}
);
```

Do some debugging and see what is not working.

Avoid using SYSTEM for testing.  Create a 'normal' (non privileged) user:
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-users-grant-them-privileges-and-remove-them-in-oracle-database

Finally check out this series on creating a REST service with node-oracledb:

https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/build-rest-apis-for-nodejs-part-1

https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/javascript/rest-api

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your help, the problem is solved thank you one more time